# Is that proper way to use rsync command?

Tags: linux, perl, unix, rsync

```
$var = "/nfs/sc/disks/darshils/scripts/";
```

here `$var` is a string

```
system 'rsync -av $var/.*pl /scripts/';
```

system command use for in perl lang I can execute any unix command

Is that way is it possible to use $var in rsync command?
or anyother way to use $var in rsync command?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: @jww the OP is asking a question about Perl, not about `rsync`. It fits nicely here!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, but there is a proper way to use quotes.

In Perl, the string `$var` is interpolated inside double quotes (and the double quote constructions `qq{...}`) but treated literally inside single quotes (and `q{...}`). So you just want to change your `system` call to

```
system "rsync -av $var/.*pl /scripts/";
```

Answer (score 3):

You can make your `system` call a little safer.

There are two forms of `system`. The string form gives `system` one argument. The shell then interprets the string to figure out what to do. That might be something other than what you intend when you interpolate a variable. What is `$var` is something like `; rm -rf`? That `;` ends the command and allows you to start a new one.

The list form is a bit safer. None of the arguments after the command are treated specially by the shell. If there's a shell metacharacter in `$var` it's just it's literal self in this form:

```
 system 'rsync', '-av', "$var/.*pl", '/scripts/';
```

Perl also has "taint-checking" that marks data that has come from outside your program (user input, files, whatever). Tainted data is viral; use it with untainted data and you get more tainted data. When you try to use tainted data to do something outside your program (like a `system`), you get an error.

Check out [perlsec](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlsec.html). I also have a chapter on this in [Mastering Perl](https://www.masteringperl.org/). Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the Perl [File::Rsync](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Rsync) module.